# Programatically triggering a MouseMove java

Tags: java

I'm trying to register mouse movements in a game and using java.awt.Robot doesn't seem to register unless I manually move the cursor, after which the screen jumps to where all of the mouseMove() methods called(I'm trying to simulate smooth cursor movements) should've brought me beforehand.

```java
r.setAutoDelay(1);

//moves the cursor pixel by pixel
while ((Math.abs(x - fx) > 0) && (Math.abs(y - fy) > 0))
{
    r.mouseMove(x, y);

    if (x < fx)
        x++;
    else if (x > fx)
        x--;

    r.mouseMove(x, y);

    if (y < fy)
        y++;
    else if (y > fy)
        y--;
}
```

(x, y) - current screen coords
(fx, fy) - screen coords of the destination (final coords)

I'm trying to find a way to more accurately simulate user input (mainly looking into artificially triggering a MouseEvent), but all of the examples I found either weren't for java, used the Robot class, required an applet or addressed a different issue.

Is there any way I can freely mimic cursor movements?

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with delay:

```
try {
    // Screen coordinates
    Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); // get current coords
    double x = 500;
    double y = 200;
    double yC = y / x;

    // Move the cursor
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
    for(int i = (int)p.x; i < x; i++) {
        Thread.sleep(5);
        robot.mouseMove(i, (int) (yC * i));
    }

}
catch (AWTException e) {}
catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Comment: I've tried using Robot class already (actually my program is more or less exactly what you did). The way I've used it is so that it moves pixel by pixel, and it still doesn't register in game.

Comment: There is no other way to do it. You are trying to hack a game developed by experts and expect that they would leave a bug for you to exploit? You are basically trying to build a macro. Even if you somehow managed to make it move, you would be stuck with some kind of auth mechanism like google captcha to verify the human interaction. It is very difficult to get through such a mechanism.

Comment: The game I'd use this for is Minecraft and the way that the server that I'd use this for verifies 'human interaction' is by moving the mouse. The way I'm trying to approach this is by artificially inputing MouseEvents (or something like that) into the system overall instead of directly into the game.
Also for the record someone (Xcom6000 on yt) figured out how to manipulate the rng of the game (without hacking), and I'm using an earlier version than the one he discovered it on.